# Java Files.walkTree

Tags: java, path

Только начал изучать Java и дойдя о раздела Path и Files столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

**Задача:** Вывести в консоль все папки и подпапки каталога.

Решил не делать это через рекурсию, а освоить метод Files.walkFileTree.
Казалось бы, все просто. Задать проверку isDirectory для attrs в FileVisitResult во время провода директории и дело с концом. Однако, по какой то причине, эта проверка не действует и в список ничего не добавляется. Метод просто "бурится" до конца директории, игнорируя подпапки, как таковые.
Что то близко похожее к желаемому результату было получено при помощи метода postVisitDirectory, но там в список, помимо подкатологов, подавлялась папка самой директории, где происходит поиск, что не совсем корректно.
Что я делаю не так?

```
public class Prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        for (String H : getFileTree("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\untitled1\\JR")) {
            System.out.println(H);
        }}

        public static List<String> getFileTree(String root) throws IOException {
        List<String> a  = new ArrayList<>();

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(root), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
               if(attrs.isDirectory())
              a.add(attrs.toString());

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });

        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска директорий нужно переопределить соседний метод `preVisitDirectory`

```
public static List<String> getFileTree(String root) throws IOException {
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(root), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            a.add(dir.toString());
            return super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs);
        }
    });
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. изначальная директория, в которой происходит поиск каталогов/подкаталогов (в моём случае JR), так или иначе будет выводиться, хоть она в списке не нужна и с этим ничего не поделать?
И почему мы возвращаем super, а не используем CONTINUE?

Comment: Корневая директория тоже учитывается в обходе. Такова логика работы метода, то что в ней лежит нас в общем случае тоже интересует. Можете просто игнорировать первую запись, если она вам не нужна. Т.к. мы пользуемся побочным результатом работы метода, нам вообще все равно что возвращать. Такую конструкцию предлагает IDE по умолчанию, если вскрыть метод родительского класса super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs); - мы найдем в return тот же FileVisitResult.CONTINUE; ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

```
    List<Path> list = null;
    try {
        Path path = Path.of(root);
        list = Files.walk(path).filter(p -> p != path && p.toFile().isDirectory()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO implement better exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```